# JPopupMenu Menu Not Appearing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpopupmenu

This is the code for my JPopupMenu and how I added it, it is supposed to respond when I right click the table:

```
    JMenuItem deleteRows = new JMenuItem("Delete Row");
    popup.add(deleteRows);

    personTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                popup.show(personTable, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }

    });
```

I am not sure why the popup menu is not appearing when I right-click the table in the application. I would appreciate it if somebody told me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Does the mousePressed execute? Can you verify if it's executed add println("executed") and see the console if it has this output?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try using some println's to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger for a popup is different for different OS's, you can't simply use `mousePressed` and your certainly shouldn't be using `e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3`

From [How to use Menus, Bringing up a PopupMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup)

> The exact gesture that should bring up a popup menu varies by look and feel. In Microsoft Windows, the user by convention brings up a popup menu by releasing the right mouse button while the cursor is over a component that is popup-enabled. In the Java look and feel, the customary trigger is either pressing the right mouse button (for a popup that goes away when the button is released) or clicking it (for a popup that stays up).

Instead, you should be checking for each of the mouse events, `pressed`, `released` and `clicked`.  You should also be using `MouseEvent#isPopupTrigger` to determine if the event is a popup trigger for the OS.

Having said all that, it would be simpler to just us [`JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu)) and let it decide instead

```
personTable.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
```

## Runnable example...

[image: Popup]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(10, 10);
                JTable table = new JTable(model);

                JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem("I'll be your menu for today");
                JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
                popup.add(mi);

                table.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: When I put in the code above and ran the application, nothing happened. Is there something you have to do to activate it.

Comment: Nope, should have worked. Give me a few minutes, I'll make a test.  Oh, is there any rows in your table?

Comment: Yes, there are rows when I enter info

Comment: Thanks, actually, that fixed it. I'll click the check by your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to create a popupMenu without using mouse listener:

```java
JpopupMenu popMenu = new JpopupMenu() ;
JMenuItem item = new  JMenuItem("my item") ;
popMenu.add(item);
myTable.setComponentPopupMenu(popMenu);
```